# How does combining 55% probability 4 times equal 96%

Tags: probability

In a video I watched about US missile defense systems, it was stated that each defensive missile has a 55% chance of being successful. In order to increase the chances of success, the US will launch 4 missiles at 1 target. According to this video, this increases the probability of destruction of the missile up to 96%. Is this accurate and how is this 96% calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculate the chance all four missiles will *not* be successful, which assuming independence, is $(.45)^4$.  The probability at least one will be successful is $1$ minus that probability.

Comment: To be clear, this calculation assumes that the events of different missiles being successful are independent. Whether that's a reasonable assumption depends on information we may not have.